# Cannot Position subview properly

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview

I have a subview named courseOptionsView that I want to show and hide with buttons and under certain conditions. When I use a swipe gesture the view works and is positioned correctly, but when I make the exact same call to the function with another button it repositions it, but it repositions it to the original position it was in instead of the coordinates I'm sending. :/ I'm stumped.

*edit
It seems that when I ++ or -- from cHNumber it resets subview. Any ideas?

```
 IBOutlet UIView *courseOptionsView; 
- (IBAction)nextHole:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)showCourseOptionsView:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)hideCourseOptionsView:(id)sender;


//show and hide functions
-(void) showCourseOptions{
    if(activeRound){
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
        [courseOptionsView setFrame:CGRectMake(50, 44, 200, 455)];
    }
}
-(void) hideCourseOptions{
    if(activeRound){
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
        [courseOptionsView setFrame:CGRectMake(-200, 44, 200, 455)];
    }
}
// swipe calls
- (IBAction)showCourseOptionsView:(id)sender {
    [self showCourseOptions];
}

- (IBAction)hideCourseOptionsView:(id)sender {
    [self hideCourseOptions];
}
//button call
- (IBAction)nextHole:(id)sender
{
    int totalStrokes = 0;
    int totalPlusMinus = 0;
    //[courseOptionsView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 44, 200, 455)];
    //[self showCourseOptions];

    //save current hole
    if(cHStrokes != [[currentRound objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"hole%i",cHNumber]] intValue] ||
       cHPutts != [[currentRound objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"hole%i_putts",cHNumber]] intValue]){
        [self saveCurrentHole];
    }
    // calculate and display +/- and strokes
    for (int i = 0; i < ([currentRound count]/2); i++){
        totalStrokes += [[currentRound objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"hole%i",i+1]] intValue];
        totalPlusMinus += [[[selectedScoreCardData objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"hole%i_par",i+1]] intValue];
    }
    totalPlusMinus = totalStrokes - totalPlusMinus;
    self.totalStrokesLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", totalStrokes];
    self.totalPlusMinusLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",totalPlusMinus];
        //set to next hole
    /*------------------- 
    |   SHOW VIEW HERE 
    --------------------*/
    if(cHNumber == 17){
        self.nextHoleButton.enabled = NO;
        [self showCourseOptions];
    }
    if(cHNumber == 1){
        self.prevHoleButton.enabled = YES;
    }
    cHNumber ++;
    self.cHNumberLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", cHNumber];
    [self populateScoreCard];
    [strokePickerView reloadAllComponents];
    if(([currentRound count]/2) < cHNumber){

        [strokePickerView selectRow:cHStrokes - 1 inComponent:0 animated:YES];
        [strokePickerView selectRow:0 inComponent:1 animated:YES];
    }else{
        [strokePickerView selectRow:[[currentRound objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"hole%i",cHNumber]] intValue] - 1 inComponent:0 animated:YES];
        [strokePickerView selectRow:[[currentRound objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"hole%i_putts",cHNumber]] intValue] inComponent:1 animated:YES];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that maybe after you position the view you are calling another function that changes the layout again. A possible candidate is `populateScoreCard`.